# Why local git repo does not see the merge executed on origin?

Tags: git, git-merge

I created a pull request on branch "feature/90...".
I merged it in GitHub to the master branch (named "main").
[image]

The branch is not deleted.
On VS Code I can switch to master and fetch master from origin.
Why I don't see teh merge in VS Code "GitGraph" plugin and neither on SourceTree?

[image]

[image]

Also fetching/pulling from bot hbranches does not change it, the "merge to master" line is not represented.
To see it I can merge the branch to master also locally and this is the result:
(ignore the extra "clenup" commit on master branch)

[image]

Is it possible to have the merge operation executed on the origin also "visible"/"replicated" on the local repository copy?
Why the pull/fetch does not show it?

Comment: Please don't update your question to include the answer, especially after the answer has been given. The answer field is where answers go. The correct procedure is just to accept / upvote the correct answer and move on. Your post-answer edits would have been appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Also your "despite the description does not give an hint about it" is just wrong. Yes, the name is misleading, but the description is quite clear that Merge makes a merge commit, and the others do _not_ say that. Only a merge commit has the two-parent topology the lack of which you are complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because what you did on GitHub was *not* a merge. You did a "Squash and merge" instead. (I know that from looking at the screenshot in your *other* question on this topic.)

GitHub offers three ways to accept a pull request: Merge, Rebase and Merge, and Squash and Merge. The second two, despite the name, are *not merges*. They do create a new commit on main, which I can actually manage to see in your annoyingly blanked out diagrams; but they do *not* result in a merge topology (a commit with two parents) which is what you are looking for (and which is what you created on local when you performed a true merge locally).

If you *wanted* a merge topology you should have asked GitHub to do a true Merge. However, many companies do not allow this; they configure GitHub to do a Squash and Merge instead. That's okay, but then you must not look for merge topology. That topology is exactly what Squash and Merge is designed to avoid.

---

(Incidentally, you should have deleted your feature branch. A PR branch that is closed by Squash and Merge is useless and should be deleted immediately. Otherwise there is a danger that you might try to add more commits to it and try to Squash and Merge it *again*, which will result in horrible merge conflicts and other nasty side effects.)

Comment: For more, see my essay https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/